# How to maintain the selected image state in gallery while Scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am Using gallery to show images and changing the gallery item's background on LongClick.But when I scroll the gallery, it is coming in original state means its showing the original image instead of the changed image.

I am not able to maintain the gallery item's selected state.

kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

well, this is a common case when you use recycled view in your adapter. You can save the selected position, then in your getView() method to check if the position equals the selected position, if yes, set the view selected state.